# How do you go by solving this kind of linear differential equation? $\frac{df(y)}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)f(y) = Q(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am stumped at this question our instructor gave as at class. This is the differential equation:

$\frac{df(y)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x)$

Within my understanding, this is a general form of a linear differential equation: $\frac{dy}{dx} + P(x)y = Q(x)$. However, the first term is what I'm really interested about, where two derivative operators are multiplied. Is $\frac{df(y)}{dy} \frac{dy}{dx}$ the same as $\frac{dy}{dx}$? If it is, how is it evaluated and simplified to the latter?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: The equation in the title is different from the first equation in the question: the term $P(x)f(y)$ in the former is replaced with $P(x)y$ in the latter.

Comment: You’re solving for $y$ and $f$ is given, right?